# How to set CSS configuration of MathJax 2.7.8 to change text-color of equations globally

Tags: css, colors, configuration, styles, mathjax

I'm using mathjax in a project and I've been trying to change the colors of all math. I am loading the following configuration file:

```
window.MathJax = {
  jax: ['input/TeX', 'output/HTML-CSS'],
  extensions: ['tex2jax.js'],

  displayAlign: 'center',

  TeX: {
    extensions: ['AMSmath.js', 'AMSsymbols.js', 'AMScd.js'],
    Macros: {
      e: '{\\textrm{e}}',
      R: '{\\mathbb{R}}', // this is working!
      Z: '{\\mathbb Z}',
      KK: '{\\mathbb{K}}'
    }
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ['\\(', '\\)']
    ],
    displayMath: [
      ['$$', '$$'],
      ['\\[', '\\]']
    ],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  'HTML-CSS': {
    fonts: ['TeX'],
    styles: {
      scale: 110,
      '.MathJax': { padding: '1em 0.1em', color: 'green ! important' }, //Not working
      '.MathJax_Display': { 'text-align': 'center' }
    }
  },
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  menuSettings: { zoom: 'Double-Click', mpContext: true, mpMouse: true }
}
```

Everything is apparently working but the HTML-CCS:styles part is not working. I couldn't find a proper reference for this, and I don't know if this version of MathJax (2.7.8) is using a different format.
 In this project I'm using nuxt and vuetify, I don't know if this is the problem, but I turn off vuetify and still the styles are not applied to the math display.
Thanks very much for any help,
Milton.

Answer (score 0):

The `scale: 110` parameter is not a CSS declaration, so should not be in the `styles` block (but rather in the `HTML-CSS` block directly).  I suspect that that may be causing the styles not to be generated properly.  Try moving the `scale` up one level and see if that helps.

Note that the `HTML-CSS` output jax is the slowest one available.  You might consider switching to the CommonHTML output jax instead.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was the problem. Apparently the new versions of Mathjax changed the name of the CSS classes. The following configuration now works:

Update: Now I'm facing a different problem...that configuration only works in developing mode, when deploy the mathjax css is not working...in that case I think it is the vuetify css. :-(

Update: Now it is working, also in deployed mode. I was loading Mathjax with a the pre-configuration ?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG. When I load it without that pre-configuration it works. I don't know why.

```
window.MathJax = {
  jax: ['input/TeX', 'output/CommonHTML'],
  extensions: ['tex2jax.js', 'Safe.js'],
  styles: {
    '.mjx-chtml': { padding: '0.1em 0.1em' }, //new names of the selectors, working!
    '.MJXc-display, .mjx-chtml': { color: 'green' }
  },
  displayAlign: 'center',

  TeX: {
    extensions: ['AMSmath.js', 'AMSsymbols.js', 'AMScd.js'],
    Macros: {
      e: '{\\textrm{e}}',
      R: '{\\mathbb{R}}',
      Z: '{\\mathbb Z}',
      KK: '{\\mathbb{K}}'
    }
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ['\\(', '\\)']
    ],
    displayMath: [
      ['$$', '$$'],
      ['\\[', '\\]']
    ],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  CommonHTML: {
    scale: 105,
    linebreaks: { automatic: true }

  },
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  menuSettings: { zoom: 'None', mpContext: true, mpMouse: true }
}
```

Note that styles are in the core configurations, outside the CommonHTML item.
Thanks for the help!
Milton.